# How can I offset the noise texture on a generated grid by the position it eventually gets instanced at?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I created a grid, then used instance on point to place a grid of grids, which I want to adjust the heightmap of, into what looks like a connected landscape.

Right now the instanced grids are all identical:
[image]

How do I offset the noise texture use for the heightmap by the position it eventually gets instanced at?

Position+vector math lets me adjust the position, but it's still identical on every grid.

[image]

**EDIT: Attempt using Chris's setup**

[image]

(still all look the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this one doesn`t work either, then the error is somewhere else.

[image]

This is a simplified version of @Chris's solution, because the nodes `Attribute Capture` are really not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

with this node setup:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

You have to use the realize instance node that it works. I add the positions of the grids to capture the "real" position and add it, so that it is one big fitting landscape.

Comment: I couldn't immediately see why all the capturing and adding was needed.. @stackers wants to move the tiles about and have the texture stick, I guess?

Comment: You are free to answer with less nodes…but I think this is the result he wants…

Comment: i tried copying this setup but still got every chunk looking the same

Comment: show me your node setup or better provide blend file, then i will have a look

Comment: and i don't know whether this matters...but i am using Blender 3.3 alpha....